# How to iterate over attribute names of an custom object

Tags: python

Hi I have a JSON Object in my python code and I use them as object in my code. Its type is JSONHelper.X which is a custom class I wrote which reads a json file and transform its to a object for using easily.

```
{
   "Gui":{
      "Images":{
         "Logo1":"url1",
         "Logo2":"url2",
         "Logo3":"url3",
         "Logo4":"url4",
         "Logo5":"url5"
      }
   }
}
```

How can I retrive pair of attribute name and value from this object to give another class as parameter. JSONHelper object does not seem to have **dict** attribute so I can not say Gui.Images.keys(). When I print Gui.Images I only get values.

I can reach attribute names as below. Is there any better way to do this?

```
    def prop_names(self):
            l = []
            public_props = (name for name in dir(self.settings.Images) if not name.startswith('_'))
            for name in public_props:
                if name is not "count" and name is not "index":
                    print(name)
            print(l
)
output: 
Logo1
Logo2
Logo3
Logo4
Logo5
```

Comment: Why not just use an ordinary dictionary?

Comment: @Barmar When I do `Gui.__dict__ `it says `'X' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Comment: I mean why are you converting it to an object instead of just using the dictionary that `json.load()` returns?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your JSON helper string into dictionary using json.load (see comments from Barmar).  From there you can access the keys values that you want.

```
import json
import itertools

j="""{
   "Gui":{
      "Images":{
         "Logo1":"url1",
         "Logo2":"url2",
         "Logo3":"url3",
         "Logo4":"url4",
         "Logo5":"url5"
      }
   }
}""" 
d = json.loads(j)
l = [list(d[k1][k2].keys()) for k1 in d.keys() for k2 in d[k1].keys()]
print(list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(l)))
```

Result:

```
['Logo1', 'Logo2', 'Logo3', 'Logo4', 'Logo5']
```